# Cheap way to get from Amsterdam to Prague: train?

Tags: public-transport, budget, germany, netherlands, czech-republic

I'm planning to a trip from Budapest to Amsterdam, then to Prague, and back to Budapest. It's very cheap to get from Budapest to Amsterdam using Wizz air, but the return flight is costly, so I was thinking of taking a train.

I know you can do Amsterdam to Prague via Cologne or Berlin. Which is better? What other options exist? I'm just trying to be as thrifty as possible.

Comment: What does best mean for you? I'm afraid this question is hard to answer without knowing budget and personal preference.

Comment: @JoErNanO The headline question is the kind that usually deserves this type of comments but I think the text explains that in quite some details (Wizz Air too expensive - which tells a lot about both budget and preferences, specific question is comparing two train options w.r.t. to budget, being thrifty is paramount and hitchhiking is an option).

Comment: Amsterdam to cologne is only 19 euros, but then you get stuck doing Cologne to Prague, which I can't find for under 99 euros, so I was thinking of doing Amsterdam to Berlin, Berlin to Prague instead, but they won't list the prices for Berlin to Prague online (I guess I have to call them). I just wanted to know if those were really my best options. I looked into them because of http://www.seat61.com/, but some of the information on that site seems to be a bit out of date (namely prices). I would also consider hitchhiking if people can confirm that there's a good route. Only speak En/Fr though.

Comment: @gannex Amsterdam > Prague by ICE is about 103 euro so it would be cheaper to take a direct route then. nsinternational.nl is the website where you can find all international trains going from The Netherlands. Also I don't think Hitchhiking would be successful in The Netherlands, we don't see them very often and I've never heard of anyone, other than a truck driver maybe, picking one up.

Comment: gannex, your best bet (I think) is perhaps some sort of cheap bus line?  or, just try to find the cheapest train fare possible.  Travel around Europe is not cheap unless (as you have) you just stumble on to a cheap airfare.  Regarding hitchhiking I *believe* it is extremely unlikely, safe but unlikely.

Comment: [The Man in Seat 61 has a suggested route from the Netherlands to Prague by train](http://seat61.com/Czech.htm#London%20to%20Prague%20by%20ferry). Based on that, *his best* route says to go via *both* Cologne *and* Berlin!

Comment: Was writing my answer as the question got closed, so here is a pastebin instead covering all  your options: http://pastebin.com/dBkYTeVa

Comment: I think this question is clear enough. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Try Student Agency. Just google for the dates you want. It is quite cheap sometimes. https://bustickets.studentagency.eu/Booking/from/10202030/to/Praha/tarif/REGULAR/departure/20160727/retdep/20160727/return/false?0#search-results. It might take about 17-18 hours though but is usually punctual.

Comment: Especially if you are travelling in a small group (<=5) and are not in a hurry, it might be very worthwhile to check out the possibilities of a Schoenes Wochenende Ticket. This allows you and up to 4 others to travel with regional trains in the weekends, for 36EUR+4EUR per person. I got from Emmerich (across the NL-DE border) to Munich in about 11 hours once, and from Munich to the Prague border in 2 so you might need an extra night, though. https://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/prices/germany/schoenes-wochenende-ticket.shtml

Answer (score 8):

Bus services like Flixbus (And I believe there are many others, I see these buses often here) can take you from Amsterdam Sloterdijk to Prague. This will cost you from 45 euro to 65 euro, depending on how many stops you have. If you get the 65 euro, nonstop ride it will take you 12 hours. 45 euro and 1 stop is about 18 hours.

Amsterdam Sloterdijk is a trains station close to Amsterdam Centraal. Very accessible from Amsterdam Centraal and Schiphol Airport.

As requested; on the [flixbus website](https://shop.flixbus.com/search?route=Amsterdam-Prague%20Main%20Railway%20Station&rideDate=12.07.2016&adults=1&children=0&bikes=0&departureCity=1334&departureStation=&arrivalCity=1374&arrivalStation=6988&currency=EUR) you can find information about frequency and detailed pricing. The Flixbus buses leave about 5-6 times  day, every day.

Comment: Can you add a link and/or information about the frequency/days-of-week at which this ride is available?

Comment: We aggregate the buses of Flix, RegioJet (new name of Student Agency), and a few others at Busbud, book in advance for cheap tickets. https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-amsterdam-prague/r/u173zq-u2fkbn

Comment: If I'm going to take a bus though, shouldn't I just hitchhike?

Comment: This certainly seems like a good option though, price-wise.

Comment: @gannex I doubt you'll have much luck hitchhiking, it's not big here and I've never heard of anyone picking up a hitchhiker here. Although I am not an expert on that matter. Maybe you can find info on forums or Facebook groups dedicated to hitchhiking.

Comment: you mean in the Netherlands, or in this part of Europe in general?

Comment: @gannex The Netherlands, I am not familiar with any other parts. If you take the bus you at least have a certainty that you will arrive at the destination within a certain amount of time. Finding people to hitch a ride with is going to take a lot more time than the 12-18 hours of bus rides.

Answer (score 2):

[Deutsche Bahn](https://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/) has a pretty good connections finder (usually works in Europe pretty well), you can explore your train options there.

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer, since you don't provide a specific train route at a known price (also, the DB site says "Fares not available" and "cannot be booked over the Internet" for many of the options).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the train you will have to travel through Germany, that's for sure. The Deutsche Bahn has a quite good search and [as you can see](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?revia=yes&existOptimizePrice=1&country=DEU&dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KIN0001_qf-bahn_LZ003&ignoreTypeCheck=yes&S=Schiphol%20%28Airport%29&REQ0JourneyStopsSID=&REQ0JourneyStopsS0A=7&Z=PRAHA&REQ0JourneyStopsZID=&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0A=7&trip-type=single&date=Mi%2C%2020.07.16&time=8%3A00&timesel=depart&returnTimesel=depart&optimize=0&travelProfile=-1&adult-number=1&children-number=0&infant-number=0&tariffTravellerType.1=E&tariffTravellerReductionClass.1=0&tariffTravellerAge.1=&qf-trav-bday-1=&tariffTravellerReductionClass.2=0&tariffTravellerReductionClass.3=0&tariffTravellerReductionClass.4=0&tariffTravellerReductionClass.5=0&tariffClass=2&start=1&qf.bahn.button.suchen=) the fastest connections are usually via Frankfurt and Nuremberg or Berlin.

If you want to be cheap, Deutsche Bahn has a Sparpreis (which translates to *saver fare*). The thing is that only one point of your journey (so either start or destination) can be in a foreign country. So what you could do is split up your journey into two tickets. For example if you search for next Wednesday you could search for a saver fare from Schiphol to Berlin), the cheapest being 44€:

[image]

and then you search for another ticket, taking you from Berlin to Prague (cheapest for 39€):

[image]

So this would in total be **83€**, but of course it heavily depends on your times and . Also it might make sense to also search via Nuremberg and see if it has any cheap saver fares.

Comment: It is easier to find cheap tickets when you book farther ahead. This is not just for trains but for most long distance travel.